# hadoop-2.2.0 compalition failing on Mac OS X 64bit

Tags: hadoop, env, javah

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:native-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-7:javah (default) on project hadoop-common: Error running javah command: Error executing command line: Error setting up environmental variables: Cannot run program "env": error=20, Not a directory -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in windows 8. Here's what I did:

1. Ensure javah is copied to the path that's specified as JAVA_HOME.
2. Tools.jar should be copied to to the corresponding lib folder of JAVA_HOME. For ex: if JAVA_HOME is c:..\jre, tools.jar should be copied to c:..\jre\lib.

This resolved the above said error. Hope this helps.